# org.cementj.base.ValueObject package in our project?

Tags: java

I want to use class "org.cementj.base.ValueObject" in our project but its not find any jar regarding this class.
I want to use package of this jar And know how to import this package in eclipse.

Comment: You first need to know which jar has this class. Then you can setup the [classpath in eclipse](http://oopbook.com/java-classpath-2/classpath-in-eclipse/). Also, I highly recommend using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) to manage dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First you download the cementJ Api.Here is the link for download
https://sourceforge.net/projects/cementj/postdownload?source=dlp
Extract the zip and add jars in your project.